What does Satan get out of being evil?
This question is regarding the Catholic view.
Why did Satan and the other demons rebel against God?  What do they get out of it?
Demons are outside of time so they perceive everything in one eternal moment [sic].  They do not have physical inclinations that could lead them to sin.  Unlike humans they perceive all of their knowledge at the same time, which means they couldn’t forget or not take into consideration the fact of God’s omnipotence and their own damnation for disobeying Him. Wouldn’t they also know that the only reason God allows them to rebel against Him is to bring some greater good out of it, which would defeat the purpose of their actions?  Wouldn’t it have been in their personal interest to not rebel against God since hell is the worst thing and it far outweighs whatever they got out of rebelling? This makes it seem like they were irrational, but how can such beings be irrational?
some quotes from Catholic Answers:

When the angels made their initial choice to love and serve the Lord or not, they perfectly saw—according to their angelic natures—the irrevocably eternal consequences of their actions. That is, they were given the power by God to make a clear and irrevocable choice to love and serve him or not. Some chose well, while others chose very badly.


They understood the world and their decisions immediately—according to Thomas Aquinas, they have no active and passive intellect (I, 54, 4)—and the exercise of their free will is instantaneous and final.

I don't know whether they are strictly atemporal or not, but whatever they are, the nature of their decision was such that there was no going back despite God's infinite mercy.
Addendum: Angels do not know the future (ST I.57.3) Also, this question differs in no way from the question of why humans choose damnation.  The answer to both questions is that there is no answer.  This is because free will by definition is the terminus ad quem of explanation. The only explanation for an act of free will is God; there's no intervening created explanation.  So the closest thing to an answer of this question is that they rebelled in order to manifest God's attribute of justice.

Why do you think sin is primarily linked to physicality?  Also, demons are not omniscient or omnipresent.

@MikeBorden  I don't think physicality is necessary for sin, but it makes sense that physical beings sin since we have bodily inclinations, we can forget things, and we can be deceived.  I just find it hard to comprehend why angels would rebel against God.  As far as I understand the Catholic teaching, demons are omniscient and omnipresent.  This is because they are non-physical which means they are present everywhere at all times which means they know everything that has happened and will happen, and they know it all at once since they do not experience the passing of time.

Nothing. Satan is the premier nihilist. They say misery loves company, but does he benefit from his irrational choices? No, not in the slightest. What possible benefit could there be in being damned forever?

I don't see where in Catholic theology devils are presumed to be omniscient.

Agree with @pygosceles and Mike Borden.  To wmasse: Are you sure demons are outside time and are omniscient?  See 5 Myths about Angels and Demons.

It took a while for the Angel to get to Daniel in response to his prayer.  Sin manifests in our physicality but it is ultimately a spiritual matter.

@GratefulDisciple  I added to the question in response to your comment.

@wmasse  It is the Catholic doctrine that those physical things you mention are caused by sin.  Had mankind not fallen, our bodies would be obedient to our wills.

The question should be, "Why and what make Lucifer and the third of the angels rebel against God?  Surely, Satan is getting a deceive and lost soul to suffer eternally in hell, and this means, Satan are opposing the Divine Plan of God, as God desires all men be saved.. -1Timothy2:4... Clearly, when Lucifer was cast out, he do not accept the Divine Plan of God. The supporting question is, "What is the Divine Plan of God, that He revealed to the Heavenly Host? It's about a Woman, who is destined to be crown as Sovereign Queen, and they all must serve and bow down, like angel Gabriel did. -Ave!

St. Thomas Aquinas answers the question "What did the angel [Lucifer] seek in sinning?" (Summa Theologica I q. 63 a. 3), saying: "the devil desired to be as God". The Devil did not seek to be equal to God; in his angelic intelligence, he knows that's not possible, but he sought to be like God. St. Thomas explains that one can desire to be Godlike without sin, but whenever one tries to be like God in what pertains to God alone, usurping Him—e.g., "playing God" like evil scientists do—then that is sinful.


1...  a useful answer... but it is important to note that Aquinas adds "he sought to have dominion over others; wherein he also perversely wished to be like unto God." In that sense he also sought to be like humans, to whom God gave the blessing of dominion.


@DanFefferman "he also sought to be like humans" Yes, maybe. Satan was envious that the Second Person of the Holy Trinity took on a human nature; he thought He should take on an angelic nature instead.

If Lucifer desires to become like God, then he clearly wanted to be look upon as a powerful being, and of of course, Lucifer desires adoration and worship by creatures. That's why, we had seen numerous pagan goddesses, all seeking the worship of men. Lucifer wanted to sit on the Throne, where the Spirit of Wisdom sits, as described by Solomon in Wisdom chapter, ".. give me Wisdom that sits on the Throne".Did Lucifer, also asked God, to anoint him with Wisdom that sits on the Throne at the Holy Mountain, but God did not answer his pleading?

The Catechism states:

391 Behind the disobedient choice of our first parents lurks a seductive voice, opposed to God, which makes them fall into death out of envy. Scripture and the Church's Tradition see in this being a fallen angel, called "Satan" or the "devil". The Church teaches that Satan was at first a good angel, made by God: "The devil and the other demons were indeed created naturally good by God, but they became evil by their own doing."
392 Scripture speaks of a sin of these angels. This "fall" consists in the free choice of these created spirits, who radically and irrevocably rejected God and his reign. We find a reflection of that rebellion in the tempter's words to our first parents: "You will be like God." The devil "has sinned from the beginning"; he is "a liar and the father of lies".
393 It is the irrevocable character of their choice, and not a defect in the infinite divine mercy, that makes the angels' sin unforgivable. "There is no repentance for the angels after their fall, just as there is no repentance for men after death."
394 Scripture witnesses to the disastrous influence of the one Jesus calls "a murderer from the beginning", who would even try to divert Jesus from the mission received from his Father. "The reason the Son of God appeared was to destroy the works of the devil." In its consequences the gravest of these works was the mendacious seduction that led man to disobey God.
395 The power of Satan is, nonetheless, not infinite. He is only a creature, powerful from the fact that he is pure spirit, but still a creature. He cannot prevent the building up of God's reign. Although Satan may act in the world out of hatred for God and his kingdom in Christ Jesus, and although his action may cause grave injuries - of a spiritual nature and, indirectly, even of a physical nature - to each man and to society, the action is permitted by divine providence which with strength and gentleness guides human and cosmic history. It is a great mystery that providence should permit diabolical activity, but "we know that in everything God works for good with those who love him."

You will find little official teaching about the why. You could say the Catholic Church is focussed on Christ, men, salvation and not so much on why Satan did what he did. We know he did, but what he got out of it?

What does Satan get out of being evil?
Answer: A morbid sense of satisfaction that he and his satellites are creating a maximum amount of destruction amongst the souls of mankind by leading as many as he can to dwell with him in Hell. Satan does not know what love is and uniquely desires to diminish God’s glory in heaven! To this end he tempts all men to fall into sin and hopes they refuse to saving graces that Christ Jesus gained for all mankind on the Cross. This is his end game and his is all he gets out of being evil.

Be sober and watch: because your adversary the devil, as a roaring lion, goeth about seeking whom he may devour. - 1 Peter 5:8

Satan hates all God, the Holy Angels, the Saints in Heaven, the Virgin Mary and all men as well as the Church founded by Jesus Christ. He has no love!
I would like to offer two private revelations as Catholic sources that although not an obligation of faith to believe in, but do have some insights to show Satan’s dispositions towards men and the Catholic Church.
The first is the is taken from the famous vision of Pope Leo XIII in 1884!

On October 13, 1884, exactly 33 years to the day before the Miracle of the Sun in Fatima, Pope Leo XIII had a terrifying vision of the future of the Church. With a handful of cardinals and Vatican staff members in attendance, Pope Leo XIII had finished celebrating Mass in the Vatican Chapel. He suddenly stopped at the foot of the altar, his face having turned ashen white, and remained there standing for about ten minutes in a trance-like state.
Later, when asked what had happened, Pope Leo XIII said that as he was about to leave the altar he heard two voices. One voice was of a kind and gentle nature, while the other voice was guttural and grating. He listened to the voices, which seemed to emanate from the tabernacle, and overheard the following conversation:

The voice of Satan in his pride, boasted to our Lord:


“I can destroy your Church.”


The gentle voice of our Lord:


“You can? Then go ahead and do so.”


Satan:


“To do so, I need more time and more power.”


Our Lord:


“How much time? How much power?


Satan:


“75 to 100 years, and a greater power over those
who will give themselves over to my service.”


Our Lord:


“You have the time, you will have the power. Do with them what you will.”

After having the vision, Pope Leo immediately went from the Vatican Chapel to his private office and wrote the “Prayer to Saint Michael”, giving with it the instructions that it be prayed after all Low Masses.
The practice of reciting this powerful prayer after Mass continue for decades, until it was officially suppressed after Vatican II.  Removing the obligation to recite this prayer (along with the three Hail Marys, the Hail Holy Queen, and the prayer for the Church) after Low Mass did not mean forbidding its use either privately or publicly, and Pope Saint John Paul II recommended its use, saying:

“Although this prayer is no longer recited at the end of Mass, I ask everyone not to forget it and to recite it to obtain help in the battle against the forces of darkness and against the spirit of this world.”

The Terrifying Vision That Led Pope Leo XIII To Write The Saint Michael Prayer

The second is from the not so well known Letter from Hell!

Although I hate the devil, I like him because he and his helpers, the angels that fell with him at the beginning of time, strive to cause the loss of the people on earth. There are myriad demons. Uncountable numbers of them who wander through the world, like a swarm of flies, without their presence even being suspected.
It does not fall to us who have been condemned to tempt you; that is left to the fallen spirits. Our torments increase every time they bring another soul to Hell, but hatred is capable of anything.

Other examples from the saints can be found here and there.

The root of sin, in Catholic theology, is concupiscence.

In its widest acceptation, concupiscence is any yearning of the soul
for good; in its strict and specific acceptation, a desire of the
lower appetite contrary to reason.

In that sense, even sin comes from a twisted desire for goodness. People don't set out to be evil, but they become evil when their desires do not align with God's will and they eventually determine to oppose Him. We get a clue of how this applies to the angels from the letter of Jude:

6 The angels too, who did not keep to their own domain but deserted
their proper dwelling, he has kept in eternal chains, in gloom, for
the judgment of the great day. 7 Likewise, Sodom, Gomorrah, and the
surrounding towns, which, in the same manner as they, indulged in
sexual promiscuity and practiced unnatural vice, serve as an example
by undergoing a punishment of eternal fire.

This implies that the angels were motivated by lust. This seems to be based on Gen. 6 and the Book of Enoch, which describes these events in considerable detail.

1 And it came to pass when the children of men had multiplied that in
those days were born unto 2 them beautiful and comely daughters. And
the angels, the children of the heaven, saw and lusted after them, and
said to one another: 'Come, let us choose us wives from among the
children of men and beget us children.' (Enoch 6)

Of course, the idea of angels begetting physical children cannot be taken literally. But it terms of motivation, going back to story of the Garden of Eden, here is a possibility: Before the Fall, Lucifer was the closest one to God. But after Adam and Eve were created, he (as a servant to God) sensed that God loved them (his children) more. His feeling of jealousy grew as Adam and Eve matured. He was especially attracted to Eve, because of her beauty. So he ventured to seduce her to eat of the forbidden fruit, thinking that in so doing he would become like god to her and Adam. The Bible (Isaiah 14) hints of this when it says:

How you have fallen from the heavens,
O Morning Star, son of the dawn!... 13 In your heart you said:
“I will scale the heavens; Above the stars of God
I will set up my throne; I will take my seat on the Mount of Assembly,
on the heights of Zaphon. 14 I will ascend above the tops of the clouds;
I will be like the Most High!

Applying this to the OP's question: Lucifer's motivation was to maintain his position as the closest one to God. The other angels likewise were motivated partly by a desire for power and partly by disordered love (lust). What did they get out of it? Something like what a physically mature man gets when he ventures to seduce a young girl: A feeling of power and the hope of love, based on the misguided belief that they will be worshiped by those they seduce and dominate.

I see two problems with this post. Satan is a spiritual being and is not influenced by concupiscence. The Book of Enoch is considered Apocrypha with the Catholic Church.

@KenGraham... the Catholic Encyclopedia says concupiscence originally means "any yearning of the soul for good." But more directly, it means  "a desire of the lower appetite contrary to reason." Both definitions apply to angels as well as humans. Augustine emphasized it is disordered desire, not desire itself, that is the problem.

I cited Enoch because it amplifies Jude and Genesis 6.  In addition Augustine and other church fathers considered it to be authentic.  But you are correct that is considered apocryphal at best.
